# Word extraction with regex string

Tags: perl, unix

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126381/regex-exercise-word-delimited-by-marker), I am able recognize the pattern `object.*` by use or regex string `m/(?<=object\.)\w*`. However, since I am unfamiliar with Linux, I cannot use the commands `sed` or `perl` properly to extract desired tokens. Thus, I need your help. My best guess is `grep -E -n object file.txt | perl -nle 'm/(?<=object\.)\w*/; print $1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` or `sed`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=object\.)\w+' file
sed -nE 's/.*object\.([[:alnum:]_]+).*/\1/p' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ESenne).

The `grep -oP` allows you to use PCRE regex (with `-P` option) and extract all matched texts (with `-o` option).

The `sed` command is more complex, it allows extracting matches (that are the last on a line) once per line: first, it suppresses the default line output with `-n` and sets the regex flavor to POSIX ERE (with `-E`), then matches a line with `object.`  + one or more alphanumeric or underscore chars captured into `\1` and replaces the full line with the Group 1 value, and only that result is returned.

Comment: Thanks, pal! I used `grep -oP '(?<=object\.)\w*' file.txt | tee output.txt`. It worked well.

Comment: May I ask your rationale to work with regex? Oftentimes it is better to ask an specialist rather than deepdive books.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` contains what the first capture (`(...)`) captured. But you don't have any captures.

Instead, you want `$&`, which contains the text matched by the pattern.

```bash
grep -E -n object file.txt | perl -nle'm/(?<=object\.)\w*/; print $&'
```

And rather than printing unconditionally, you can print only if a match is found, eliminating the need for `grep`.

```bash
perl -nle'print $? if /(?<=object\.)\w+/' file.txt
```

Finally, we don't need the relatively-slow lookaround.

```bash
perl -nle'print $1 if /object\.(\w+)/' file.txt
```

On some systems, `grep` can also do the job using `-o` and `-P`.

```bash
grep -oP '(?<=object\.)\w+' file.txt
```

Comment: I used `awk` command to remove duplicates: `grep -oP '(?<=object\.)\w*' file.txt | awk '!a[$0]++' | tee output.txt`

Comment: Or `sort -u`. // We didn't mention it, but we changed `\w*` to `\w+` cause there's no point in matching and printing empty strings. Unless you really do want blank lines to be output?

Comment: Precisely correct!

Comment: or `sort output.txt | uniq -u`

Comment: `sort -u` is more efficient than `sort | uniq`, when available.